# When program runs, paintComponent is called inconsistently

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I am trying to understand why paintComponent is being called inconsistently when the program is ran.  In looking over previous posts, I have read all of Painting in AWT and Swing (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html ) as well as dozens of posts dealing with paintComponent.  This program is a simple one to use the MouseListener methods.  When I only run this program and do not do anything else (move mouse etc), paintComponent is sometimes called 3, 4 or 5 times.  Usually, it runs 3 or 4 times.  The inconsistency is crazy to me.  It shows how little I know.  Does someone know why?

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;    import java.awt.event.*;    import javax.swing.*;

public class EnterExit extends JFrame {
    public EnterExit(){
        super("Enter exit Frame");
        setSize( 300, 400);             
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        setLocation(00,0);
        EEPanel eep = new EEPanel();        
        getContentPane().add( eep );
        setVisible(true);       
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){
        EnterExit ee = new EnterExit();
    }
} 

public class EEPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    private boolean entered;
    private int x, y; // counter used to test why flickering when prog 1st runs;
    private int count; // troubleshooting how many times paintComponent is called.

    public EEPanel(){
        entered = false;
        count = x = y = 0;
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 50) );
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        count++;    // troubleshooting
        if(entered){
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            g.drawString("entered", 50, 150);
            System.out.println("INSIDE if count = "+count);//troubleshooting
        }else{
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            g.drawString("exited", 50, 150);
            System.out.println("INSIDE else  count = " + count );
        }
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
        entered = true;
        repaint();              // all mouse methods seem to work correctly.
        System.out.println("mouseEntered"); // all sop lines used for testing
    }


    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){ 
        entered = false; 
        repaint();
        System.out.println("mouseExited"); 
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
        x = evt.getX();
        y = evt.getY();
        repaint();
        System.out.println("mousePressed: x = " + x +"\t y = " + y);    
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("mouseClicked");}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {System.out.println("mouseReleased");}
}
```

Comment: Your `paintComponent` method should not be carrying any logic, it should simply paint the current state of the component, so, from that perspective, you shouldn't care, yes it's variable, yes it will most likely be different each time you start the program, the system is trying to come to a stable state, until it is, it needs to update your component accordingly. Based on you code, I'm not sure why you would care anyway

Comment: The code in and of itself is not so important.  I am trying to understand why it is called inconsistently.  Since I am new to GUI and Swing, it seems strange that any program, and hence the methods, would not run the same number of time every time the program is ran.  Your comments are very helpful!  I have never heard that before.  If paintComponent should not carry any logic, does that imply the idea of what this program does is bad?  Without having logic in paintComponent, is there a way to do something simple like this?

Comment: Based your code, the logic you're using is used to determine the state, so it's not "to" bad, you could simply use a Color variable and change it in the listener